# How to properly justify the small paragraph which has some equations in it

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs

I have a small question and answer kind of a paragraph, I wanted it to justify properly. how to do that

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\scshape{Comment-7:}} Page 3, equation 1: $k_{t,j}y(\zeta_{1,j})\delta(x-\zeta_{1,j}) $and similar terms should be modified to $k_{t,j}y(x,t)\delta(x-\zeta_{1,j})$.}\\
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\scshape {Response-7:}}} $\textcolor{red}{k_{t,j}y(\zeta_{1,j})\delta(x-\zeta_{1,j})}$ has been changed to $\textcolor{blue}{k_{t,j}y(x,t)\delta(x-\zeta_{t,j})}$, $\textcolor{red}{k_{r,j}y'(\zeta_{3,j})\delta'(x-\zeta_{3,j})}$ to $\textcolor{blue}{k_{r,j}y'(x,t)\delta'(x-\zeta_{r,j})}$  and  $\textcolor{red}{m_{j}y(\zeta_{2,j})\delta(x-\zeta_{2,j})}$ to $\textcolor{blue}{m_{j}y(x,t)\delta(x-\zeta_{m,j})}$. Please see Equation (1) on page 7 of the revised manuscript.   \\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use `\\` at the end of a paragraph (that was generating the badness 10000 warnings)
note space in math is ignored so you want  `...$ and ...`  not `... $and ...`

You could use `\sloppy` to justify this text allowing extra stretching of the space, but I think for such texts it is better to use `\raggedright`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\scshape{Comment-7:}} Page 3, equation 1: $k_{t,j}y(\zeta_{1,j})\delta(x-\zeta_{1,j})$ and similar terms should be modified to $k_{t,j}y(x,t)\delta(x-\zeta_{1,j})$.}

\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\scshape {Response-7:}}} $\textcolor{red}{k_{t,j}y(\zeta_{1,j})\delta(x-\zeta_{1,j})}$ has been changed to $\textcolor{blue}{k_{t,j}y(x,t)\delta(x-\zeta_{t,j})}$, $\textcolor{red}{k_{r,j}y'(\zeta_{3,j})\delta'(x-\zeta_{3,j})}$ to $\textcolor{blue}{k_{r,j}y'(x,t)\delta'(x-\zeta_{r,j})}$  and  $\textcolor{red}{m_{j}y(\zeta_{2,j})\delta(x-\zeta_{2,j})}$ to $\textcolor{blue}{m_{j}y(x,t)\delta(x-\zeta_{m,j})}$. Please see Equation (1) on page 7 of the revised manuscript.

\end{document}
```

If you just change \raggedright`to`\sloppy` you get some warnings about bad line breaks and

[image]